# ASP .NET CORE could not find file or assembly with custom assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly

I've ran into a weird problem.

I basically have my own web-stack for .NET-core which I've built into a few .dlls, and I want to reference these from another ASP CORE-solution.

VS seems to find the assemblies, where I can navigate types etc.
I can also build the project without any issues, but when IIS then runs the server I get an internal server error stating:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '**myDLL**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The referenced DLLs are in the debug-folder, and the really weird thing is that if I create a new ASP Core project in the same solution as the web-stack, I can reference and use it without any problems.

Why is this happening only when running on a project *outside* the web-stack's solution, and what can I do to make it runnable everywhere?

Comment: Have you set up your reference to be copied to the output folder? (see properties of the reference)

Comment: @Tseng Yes I tried this. Did not make a difference sadly

Comment: And you're sure you didn't tried to reference a `net4xx` library in an `netcoreapp1.x` project?

Comment: @Tseng Affirmative. Both the library and the web-project is targeting **.NETCoreApp 1.1**

Comment: Libraries shouldn't usually have to target `netcoreapp1.x`, with the very rare exception of requiring .NET Core only API which is unavailable in `netstandard1.x`. You should always try to target `netstandard`

Comment: @Tseng Would this make a difference though, since the answer below was the solution. Wouldn't there still have been a problem with my libraries' dependencies?

Comment: If all libraries use and target `netstandard` there wouldn't be issues. `netstandard` libraries can be used in `netcoreapp`'s, but not other way around. `netstandard` can also be consumed from `net452` alls, but `netcoreapp` can't

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The .NET Core Tooling in VS 2017 (< 15.3 preview) / .NET CLI < 2.0 doesn't fully support referencing assemblies on disk. You need to package the library up as a NuGet package or use a project reference ("same solution"). The technical reason is that all the required assemblies and versions are resolved during compilation and written to the `.deps.json` file. When loading arbitrary assemblies, this might fail because either the assembly or its dependencies cannot be found (or a conflict with each other).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try this and get back

Comment: This was it. I ticked the *Generate NuGet package on build*-box under the project-properties -> package, and installed the packages locally to my new web-project.

Comment: I've been searching for a couple of days for this exact answer.  Is this anywhere in the dotnetcore, dotnet cli, nuget, msbuild, or csproj documentation?  The only thing I see in any of those is where it says to either add a package reference or a reference to another project.  I guess it's sort of implied, but it would be nice to have some sort of statement for those of us trying to add on-disk assemblies.  Thanks a ton for this answer; really helpful.

Comment: I am using the VS 2017 v15.3.5, has this been fixed in this version of the VS yet? got the same issue here.

Comment: Getting the same issue in v15.4.0

Comment: Note that there are additional issues in ASP.NET Core 2.0.0 using referenced dll files in razor views that are about to be fixed in a servicing release.

Comment: Getting the same issue in v15.9.5. Any solution? @Tokfrans can you redirect me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

for load the `external dll` in `core` project, needed to:

1. vs 2017 with version 15.3 or upper.
2. `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` NuGet package installed in your project.