# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices reference in .net core 2.1?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a service to run dtsx packages in `.net core 2.1`. In .net framework you could reference using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices` which would allow you to connect to Sql Server and run dtsx packages. Is there a way to reference that in `.net core 2.1`?

Comment: Could you try to add sample and describe better in detail what you have tried so far?

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791987/how-to-run-ssis-package-in-asp-net-core-application